# Permissions needed for starting and stopping an ec2 instance using boto3 start/stop_instances command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am running into an issue when I try to start my instance using boto3's `start_instance` command where I am getting the error:
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the StartInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation` 
After a few hours of digging I am still unable to get the correct permissions for this command to run properly. I have decoded the error message and I am getting a large list of actions that I am guessing may need to be added to the instances IAM role. I have added these two roles to the ec2 instance but I am still having no luck

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:USER_ID:instance/INSTANCE_ID"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I decode my error message I get a list of "values" that don't make a ton of sense to me but here they are:

```
"items": [
            {
              "value": "iam:AttachGroupPolicy"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:AttachUserPolicy"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:ChangePassword"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:CreateAccessKey"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:CreateInstanceProfile"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:CreateLoginProfile"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:CreateRole"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:CreateUser"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:DetachUserPolicy"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:PutUserPermissionsBoundary"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:PutUserPolicy"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:UpdateAccessKey"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:UpdateAccountPasswordPolicy"
            },
            {
              "value": "iam:UpdateUser"
            },
            {
              "value": "ec2:RequestSpotInstances"
            },
            {
              "value": "ec2:RunInstances"
            },
            {
              "value": "ec2:StartInstances"
            },
            {
              "value": "organizations:CreateAccount"
            },
            {
              "value": "organizations:CreateOrganization"
            },
            {
              "value": "organizations:InviteAccountToOrganization"
            },
            {
              "value": "lambda:CreateFunction"
            },
            {
              "value": "lightsail:Create*"
            },
            {
              "value": "lightsail:Start*"
            },
            {
              "value": "lightsail:Delete*"
            },
            {
              "value": "lightsail:Update*"
            },
            {
              "value": "lightsail:GetInstanceAccessDetails"
            },
            {
              "value": "lightsail:DownloadDefaultKeyPair"
            }
          ]
```

I am simply trying to start and stop a single instance from a python script but I cannot seem to figure out why my permission's are not configured correctly. My script for starting and stopping the instance is the following

```
# code from https://github.com/niftycode/aws-ec2-start-stop/blob/36a795d57802d82709fdd61f406880c6c0c5be52/start_stop_ec2.py#L132
def start_ec2(ids):
  try:
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=ids, DryRun=True)
  except ClientError as e:
    if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
        raise
  # Dry run succeeded, run start_instances without dryrun
  try:
    response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=ids, DryRun=False)
  except ClientError as e:
    print(e)
def stop_ec2(ids):
    try:
      ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=ids, DryRun=True)
    except ClientError as e:
      if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
          raise
    # Dry run succeeded, call stop_instances without dryrun
    try:
      response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=ids, DryRun=False)
    except ClientError as e:
      print(e)

ids = ["xxxxxxxxxx"]
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-2', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxx',aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxx')

# start the instance
start_ec2(ids)
```

Comment: What is your script and how do you use these permissions in the script? Is it some instance role?

Comment: I just updated the original post with my script, I dont think there is anything wrong with how I am setting up and calling the start command because my error is only with authorization

Comment: Do you have any other credentails on the instance? They could be overwriting your instance role. Env variables, .aws/configuration?

Comment: yeah I also have AmazonEC2FullAccess and AmazonSSMFullAccess roles. When I first ran into the error the only role I had was the AmazonSSMFullAccess role

Comment: The GH link also has `credentials = read_credentials()`? What is this? read from where? boto3 manages credentails by itself.

Comment: yeah I think that was just printing the IPv4 address of the instance so in my code I am not using that function